# Anonymous user access

Tags: 7

I want all the users to access the custom defined url. But now I got error message as Access Denied, my code is as follows, I tried clearing both drupal and browser cache. Please help me,

```
function hbrowse_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['browse/restaurants'] = array(
    'title' => t('Browse Restaurants'),
    'page callback' => 'list_restaurants',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  $items['browse/cuisines'] = array(
    'title' => t('Browse Cuisines'),
    'page callback' => 'list_cuisines',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}
```

hbrowse is my module name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `access arguments`, when the callback is set to `TRUE` you dont need any parameters:

```
$items['browse/restaurants'] = array(
  'title' => t('Browse Restaurants'),
  'page callback' => 'list_restaurants',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Strae it's working now. I deactivated the module, cleared the cache and activated again. Before doing that it wasn't working. Thanks for help.

Comment: Always clear the cache when working with drupal ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
  $items['browse/restaurants'] = array(
    'title' => t('Browse Restaurants'),
    'page callback' => 'list_restaurants',
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
  );
```

Comment: I tried @Attiks but still 'Access Denied' :(

Comment: I found even for admin it is saying Access Denied error message.